# How to prove $\small\begin {cases} U \subseteq V \\ V \subseteq U + W\end{cases} \Rightarrow V \subseteq W$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

let $V,W,U$ be 3 sub-spaces of the same linear space.

Given $$\begin {cases} U \subseteq V \\ V \subseteq U + W\end{cases}$$

Can I say that $V \subseteq W$ ? And how can I prove this?

Thanks

Comment: A good starting point is looking at extreme cases; suppose $V=U$; then $V\subseteq U+W$ *for every* subspace $W$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you cannot. For instance take $\Bbb R^3$ and its canonical basis $e_1, e_2, e_3$.
Let $U = span(e_1)$, $V = span(e_1, e_2)$ and finally $W = span(e_2, e_3)$.

Then $U\subset V$, $V \subset U+W = \Bbb R^3$ but $V$ is not a subspace of $W$ since $e_1 \in V$ and $e_1 \notin W$.

More trivially you could have $U = V =\Bbb R$ and $W = \{0\}$.